# Flutter - inserted overlay going behind of software keyboard

Tags: flutter, keyboard, overlay

for keep keyboard on navigation we can use overlay instead
i created my widget Build on OverlayEntry  and inserted to overlay on my screen

[image: 1]

**TheProblem**
when i inserting my overlayEntry to overlay  the widget going behind of keyboard!

[image: 2]

**Result**
actually it should going on keyboard  like telegram

[image: 3]

and my created overlaycode is it Thank you for helping:

```
  // Remove the OverlayEntry.
  void removeHighlightOverlay() {
    if(overlayEntry != null){
      overlayEntry?.remove();
      overlayEntry = null;
    }
  }

  void createHighlightOverlay() {
    // Remove the existing OverlayEntry.
       removeHighlightOverlay();
    assert(overlayEntry == null);

    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      // Create a new OverlayEntry.
      builder: (BuildContext context) {

        // Align is used to position the highlight overlay
        // relative to the NavigationBar destination.
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            removeHighlightOverlay();
          },
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.black54,
                child: FocusedMenuDetails(
                                  menuContent: widget.menuContent,
                                  child: widget.child,
                                  childOffset: childOffset,
                                  childSize: childSize!,
                                  parentSize: parentSize!,
                                  parentOffset: parentOffset,
                                )
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    // Add the OverlayEntry to the Overlay.
    Overlay.of(context, debugRequiredFor: widget).insert(overlayEntry!);
  }
```

Comment: try with this OverlayEntry( opaque: true/false , maintainState:true/false ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opps!

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121452

there is not any way to make something like this!

have to create a future for workingAround that on flutter